# Saving multiple files with group name Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

My PSD structure

```
Group myname
layer -> Visible
Layer -> Hidden

Group 2randomname
layer -> Visible
Layer -> Hidden
```

and goes on ...

I am trying to save export groups as png, it works file when using file -> Exports -> Layers to File but my problem is its not using the group name, I want to include group name for each file, this is working when selecting all the groups and right click -> export as then selecting PNG the layers have the group names but the problem is its automatically trimming the canvas and there is no option to avoid trimming.

Is there any code or script that can do this ? any directions or help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this?

Result: [image]

```
function main()
{

    var topLayers = activeDocument.layers, // will export all top level layers (groups, backgorund layer, etc)
        exportFolder = Folder.selectDialog();

    if (exportFolder == null) return false;;

    for (var i = 0; i < topLayers.length; i++)
    {
        activeDocument.activeLayer = topLayers[i];
        toggleVisibility();
        savePng24(topLayers[i].name);
        toggleVisibility();
    }

    function savePng24(fileName)
    {
        var pngOpts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb;
        pngOpts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG
        pngOpts.PNG8 = false;
        pngOpts.transparency = true;
        activeDocument.exportDocument(new File(exportFolder + "/" + fileName + ".png"), ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, pngOpts);
    }; // end of savePng24()

    function toggleVisibility()
    {
        var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
        var list = new ActionList();
        var ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putEnumerated(cTID('Lyr '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Trgt'));
        list.putReference(ref);
        desc.putList(cTID('null'), list);
        desc.putBoolean(cTID('TglO'), true);
        executeAction(cTID('Shw '), desc, DialogModes.NO);
    }; // end of toggleVisibility()

    function cTID(s)
    {
        return app.charIDToTypeID(s);
    };

    function sTID(s)
    {
        return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);
    };

}
app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("temp", "main()");
```